# Принципы работы перехвата трафика

Tags: сеть, https, сниффер

Объясните принцип работы перехвата трафика. Вот схема подключения к сети:

WiFi роутер -> ноутбук жертвы.

Тот же самый WiFi роутер -> устройство злоумышленника.

Жертва отсылает запрос на соединение к серверу, ожидает получить сертификат в ответ. Каким образом злоумышленник может не только прослушать, что приходит в ответ жертве, но и полностью погасить ответ от сервера для жертвы для последующей подмены? Ведь подключение к интернету у них на равных условиях. Объясните, пожалуйста, как это работает?